# Showing HTML elements via WebView in android

Tags: android, html, webview

I am trying to show some basic html elements in a webview. I can do it with load datawithbaseurl method. But is there any way to check if content loaded correctly ?

Here is my html code coming from webservice.

```
   <div style="float:left;margin:0;padding:0;top:0;bottom:0"><img                src="http://exam.exam.com/upload/images/Activities/poskbhov.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```

and my webview code :

```
   webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", content.Content, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

I just want to show an image. But i want to make sure its loaded. Right now i dont have an image. WebView just shows an img object in a div right now. I would like to put this image can not shown alert.

Answer (score 0):

To link an image, build an String (HTML format) and code an IMG element:

```
String htmlContent = "<HTML>.....<img id=\"main_image\" src=yourImage.png alt=\"\"></br>.....</HTML>");
```

Load the content telling the webView were your resources are, and put your IMG in your "assets" folder with the name "yourImage.png"

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

You can also Link css file from here too!

If you want to see a full example, take a look to this project:

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

It consists on an HTTPService and, in the class `HttpServiceFragment` you can see a full (specific) implementation.

I hope it helps!!!

Comment: this html string comes from a web service. so i cant copy image to my local.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Why don't you give a dummy url (the first you find googling) to the image to make a proof of concepts? If it works, with any URL should work too.

Comment: if i didnt get you correctly i am sorry :) as i get it u say there might be something wrong with my url . Actually it is working but on any case it may not. so i wonder how can i figure that out. By the way thanks for responses

Comment: Ahh! You want to detect if an image was loaded or there was an error. I thought you were asking how to proof if your way to get the image was correct. It seems too difficult for me, and I'm not sure if it's possible... can you know that your image is not loaded when you code, for example, in HTML? If yes... how important is it? It's worths? Maybe you can make before hand an HTTPRequest and parser the result to be sure that the image is available, and, then... get de image xD